# Is there any way to assign menu icon for flask-admin generated category link?

Tags: flask, flask-admin

Is there any way to assign menu icon for flask-admin generated category link?

We can set the icon for menu item via

```
menu_icon_type=ICON_TYPE_GLYPH, menu_icon_value='glyphicon-tags'
```

But I didn't see any such named parameter existing for category link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was recently added as a feature in this pull request: https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/pull/950

Now you can use `category_icon_classes` when you initialize Admin, like this:

```
admin = Admin(
    app,
    name='My Admin',
    category_icon_classes={
        'Profiles': 'glyphicon glyphicon-wrench',
    }
)
```